# With CSS, how to style a generic, global style?

Tags: css

**Update**: this question is about **global** style.  So solution such as `#some-id .score` is NOT a solution.

At first, I was styling as

```
.score { font-size: 32px; color: #777 }
```

And the "score" is something that can happen any where, something of a global style.  But since other style actually might have:

```
#summary-panel { font-size: 13px }
```

The one with `id` will override the one just having classes (the first CSS rule in this post).  (So if score is displayed within `summary-panel` then the `font-size` will be overridden to be `13px` but the `score` style is supposed to be global and need a `32px` style.) So I was tempted to use

```
.score { font-size: 32px !important; color: #777 !important }
```

because the `!important` can act as the "second level" which override everything ordinary, and act as a global style.

Is this a good way or better way?  One catch is that if sometimes we might have a CSS issue with IE 7 (or IE 6), that we need a separate stylesheet such as `ie.css`, and in there, there might be also

```
#summary-panel { font-size: 12px !important }
```

so in this case, the `!important` will be overridden because the one having an `id` will always win over just classes.  So is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
#summary-panel.score { font-size: 32px; }
```

I guess I'm not sure how many styles you want to add or if the question is how to do this without adding any new styles, in which case I'd say there is not a better way.

Comment: +1 Select `#summary-panel.score, .score`, just to be sure every `.score` is caught anyway.

Comment: Also, OP, if someone did `#summary-panel.score { font-size: 12px !important }`, well, there's not much you can do then.

Comment: No, `.score` can happen any where, in `#summary-panel`, in `#products-list`, in ANYWHERE.  then are you going to add a rule for every where?

Comment: If you want to avoid using !important then you would want to. Or don't use ids for anything and instead use classes and you can override them with something simple like `body .score{}` which will always be more specific than just `.className` without a specific parent.

Comment: It is causing you problems to be using `id` so I'd recommend using a method that doesn't cause problems. The change won't break any browser or have any other real downsides.

Comment: but your solution is avoiding using ANY ID at all in any page.  Is that good CSS practice?

Comment: CSS has two big mechanism: IDs and Classes.  You are cutting half of the mechanism -- avoiding the total use of IDs, just to "solve" a problem.  What if other developers in your team want or need to use IDs?

Answer (score 1):

This is where you use `span`.

For example the markup:

```
<div id="sometext">
   <p>Lorem ipsum <span class="score">test</span> dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
div#sometext {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: yellow;
}

span.score {
    font-size: 42px;
    color: green;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> this question is about global style.
>   So solution  such as **#some-id .score**
>   is NOT a solution

[...]

> **.score** is NOT a solution So is there a better way?

there is no answer, all the comments you got in the first answer are valid and polite,  but I would tell you as a user, that you should not use `!important` unless in an emergency to override external code that is outwith your control, `!important` is for user styles

**CSS** is a mindset, a suggestion, your request (with a please ;) to the browsers how you would like your styles displayed - at the minute you seem to be struggling between the mindsets

The logical programmer side wants a "global" style, and I believe most programming languages have "globals" ? CSS is not a programming language it's a markup language.

Anyway, the recent last 3-4 years CSS'ers have been encouraged to "class everything"  YUI and Blueprint and other frameworks would have us do so.. but that means you should not use ID's because as you rightly point out they override.. they are the ultimate in the [CSS Specificity Wars](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html).. BUT as an efficient CSS coder you need to use ID's  - that is best practice isn't it? - so if you do need to mix them then you should group your ID selectors and if necessary group the class selectors as was suggested to you

there really is no answer here (except there no such thing as global styling unless you pass it down via ID's and inheritance, it's a coding preference rather than a right/wrong answer

Comment: Given the number of comments, I think this is a good explanation